# mvn jetty:run does not find my LoginService

Tags: java, jetty

I set-up a jetty security realm as follows (to be used with `mvn jetty:run`).
this works:

`pom.xml`

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <webAppXml>src/test/resources/jetty-test.xml</webAppXml>
      <useTestScope>true</useTestScope>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

`jetty-test.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Get name="securityHandler">
    <Set name="loginService">
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
        <Set name="name">MySecurityRealm</Set>
        <Set name="config">src/test/resources/jetty-realm.properties</Set>
        <Call name="start"/>
      </New>
    </Set>
    <Set name="checkWelcomeFiles">true</Set>
  </Get>
</Configure>
```

then I try to remove the need for the `jetty-test.xml` file, as follows:

`pom.xml`

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
   <!--      <webAppXml>src/test/resources/jetty-test.xml</webAppXml>  -->
          <useTestScope>true</useTestScope>
          <loginServices>
            <loginService implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
              <name>MySecurityRealm</name>
              <config>${basedir}/src/test/resources/jetty-realm.properties</config>
            </loginService>
          </loginServices>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

but it fails with:

```xml
2013-03-26 16:33:26.197:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@73937bc8: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No LoginService for org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator@3d47dde in org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@73937bc8
```

Any idea?

I am using this documentation:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin#Configuring_Security_Settings

Answer (score 9):

Please verify if sub-element `<name>MySecurityRealm</name>` for `<loginServices>` in your jetty-maven-plugin configuration is the same as `<realm-name>MySecurityRealm</realm-name>` for `<login-config>` in your web.xml.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have security constraints in your web.xml: [reference](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/J2EE_Declarative_Security_Overview-Web_Content_Security_Constraints.html). That is why it failed when you commented out the jetty-test.xml configuration.